# Sendmail: Setting envelope sender to a fixed value

Tags: sendmail

I need a way to configure sendmail to set the envelope sender of every message to a fixed value (say foo@bar.com). Note that this is **not** answered by any of the MASQUERADE features/macros (that I know of): I want to also override the envelope user and set it to a fixed value.

**EDIT:** Also, I do not want to masquerade the header sender. So GENERICSTABLE + MASQUERADE_ENVELOPE does not cut it, either. What I need is the equivalent of command line `sendmail -f foo@bar.com`

(Rationale: I am forced - by the customer - to go through an authenticating relay which insists on having a given envelope sender address - and no, I am not trying to circumvent any antispam measure, I merely want to send root's mail - and other administrative stuff - offsite. It is an application server, and all the mail is originated by servers, but sender addresses need to be meaningful nevertheless)

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be achieved using **ugly** but very simple hack. Put it after `MAILER(smtp)` in your `sendmail.mc` file and generate new `sendmail.cf` file.
There **MUST BE** a tab (\t) before `$:` in `R` line.
`divert(0)` cancels effects of `MAILER_DEFINITIONS`.

```
MAILER_DEFINITIONS
SEnvFromSMTP
R$+ <@foo.org.>   $: john.doe <@example.net.>
divert(0)
```

It adds extra rewriting at the end of rule set handling envelope sender address of all smtp based mailers.  The R line rewrites all *@foo.org  addresses into john.doe@example.net

You may test it using the script below:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -bt <<END
/tryflags es
/try esmtp xyz@foo.org
END
```

Comment: Xactly what I was looking for. Thx.

Comment: It is a simple, easy to maintain but uncomfortably hackish mc fix.  The right way from cf perspective would be longer and harder to maintain on long run.  Welcome to the world without perfect choices :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [FEATURE(genericstable)](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#genericstable) and [FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#masquerade_envelope) to rewrite all sender addresses in your host email domain (envelope sender and header sender (From:)).

generictable

```
@foo.org  jane.doe@example.net
```

**Do not forget** to specify domains undergoing such rewriting in sendmail.mc:

```
GENERICS_DOMAIN(`foo.org')
```

---

You may use [FEATURE(local_no_masquerade)](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html#local_no_masquerade) to exclude local email from such rewrites.

http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading_relaying.html

Comment: This is interesting, but I want the header sender to remain untouched. Editing the question to reflect this. I suspect that a LOCAL_RULE (something) is called for to nail this, but that's above my capacity to write.